Setting greyscale on plotly express bar chart
I have a 3 step problem that I'm trying to get past
#1
I got px.bar to display this bar chart in a greyscale palette with the following code
df_to_display = salary_df[salary_df["Experience Level"] == "Mid-Senior level"]

df_to_display = df_to_display[["Salary (Bucket)", "Experience in Years"]]
df_to_display = df_to_display.reset_index()
df_to_display['Frequency'] = [list(df_to_display[(df_to_display["Salary (Bucket)"] == df_to_display.iloc[i]["Salary (Bucket)"]) 
                                    & (df_to_display["Experience in Years"] <= df_to_display.iloc[i]["Experience in Years"])].count())[0] for i in df_to_display.index]

# plot structure
fig = go.Figure()
fig = px.bar(df_to_display,
             x='Salary (Bucket)',
             y='Frequency',
            #  title='Test',
             color='Experience in Years',
             barmode='overlay',
             opacity = 0.5,
             color_continuous_scale = "greys")
fig.update_traces(width = 10000, showlegend = False)

enter image description here
When I tried to cycle it through the other "Experience Level" values, the color scale seems to be ignored?
enter image description here
The code is pretty much the same. It's just that it's being iterated with the other values in the "Experience Level" field
enter image description here
#2
Then, I want to overlay the bar chart with a histogram using add_traces, but the first histogram bin doesn't start on the same point as the overlaying bar charts. Can I offset the histogram to be right on top of the bar charts?
#3
Finally, how can I disable the legend for the color scale for the bar chart?
enter image description here
The code is included
